# Why I cannot unzip a file using wildcards in PHP?

Tags: php, wildcard, unzip

I am trying to extract a zip-file using a wildcard. The point of this is to find out the said file. The file has a changing name after today's date when I download it: `test-18-02-2016.zip`. I tried like this:

```
<?php
    $myFile = 'C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/test*.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($myFile) === true) {
        $zip->extractTo('C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/');
        $zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT ok!';
    }
```

I am getting `NOT ok` ..of course, but when i switch on to `test-18-02-2016.zip`I get `ok`.
Any help to figure out why and how to resolve this is very appreciate it.

Comment: just because you can use wildcards at a shell prompt doesn't mean you can use wildcards EVERYWHERE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ZipArchive` can only represent one file at a time.  If you absolutely must use wildcards, consider passing the wildcard string into [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) and using the results it returns.

For example:

```
$myFileList = glob('C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/test*.zip');
foreach ($myFileList as $myFile) {
    echo 'Unzipping ' . $myFile . PHP_EOL;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($myFile) === true) {
        $zip->extractTo('C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/');
        $zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'NOT ok!';
    }
}
```

Comment: You have NO idea how long I have spent on this..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) that says `ZipArchive->open` accepts a wildcard path in this way. Besides, what would happen if several files matched?

Instead, find the file you want. If it's today's date...

```
$myFile = 'C:/Users/Acer/Downloads/test-'.date("d-m-Y").'.zip';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpful.